# Number of stored elements grows invisibly, in scipy sparse csc matrix, when adding slices

Tags: python, scipy, sparse-matrix

I am trying to add together slices of scipy sparse csc matrices. The way I do it now, matrices with correct values come out, but for a mysterious reason, the number of stored elements grows. It grows higher then the number of nonzero elements that are in the matrix mathematically. How?

Example:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.sparse import *

#define two dense matrices
M1_d = np.array([[0, 0, 1, 2, 3],
                 [4, 5, 0, 0, 0],
                 [6, 0, 0, 7, 8],
                 [9,10, 0,11,12],
                 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]])
M2_d = 2*M1_d

#define their sparse counterparts (in CSC form)
M1_s = csc_matrix(M1_d)
M2_s = csc_matrix(M2_d)

#doing addition with both forms works fine
Mp_d = M1_d + M2_d
Mp_s = M1_s + M2_s
```

In this normal addition both Mp_d and Mp_s have the same outcome and the correct number of elements is stored in the sparse matrix Mp_s

```
>>>Mp_s
<5x5 sparse matrix of type '<type 'numpy.int32'>'
with 12 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Column format>
```

When I on the other hand try to add only slices of the matrix together and store it in a matrix of the same size. Correct values come out, but some new elements are stored in the sparse matrix

```
#initialise some matrices as copies
Mslicep_d = M1_d.copy()
Mslicep_s = M1_s.copy()

#now I want to add only slices of the matrices
clm = [0,2,3] # I want to add these colums
Mslicep_d[:,clm] = M1_d[:,clm] + M2_d[:,clm]
Mslicep_s[:,clm] = M1_s[:,clm] + M2_s[:,clm]
```

The matrix Mslicep_s should again have 12 stored elements. It looks like it does, but:

```
>>>Mslicep_s
<5x5 sparse matrix of type '<type 'numpy.int32'>'
with 20 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Column format>
>>>Mslicep_s.toarray()
array([[ 0,  0,  3,  6,  3],
       [12,  5,  0,  0,  0],
       [18,  0,  0, 21,  8],
       [27, 10,  0, 33, 12],
       [ 0,  0,  0,  0,  0]])
```

If you count the values here, you see there are 12 of them. But the sparse matrix has 20 stored elements for some reason.

When I do multiple of these additions in a loop, the matrices get less and less sparse, which makes my code take ages. Can any one tell me where these new stored elements come from? how to prevent this? or at least how to fix it quickly at every iteration?

Thanks in advance.

EDIT: Let me be clear. I want to perform additions for which the sparsity structure of the matrix does not change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first time I do the problem addition I get a warning:

```
In [344]: Mslicep_s[:,clm] = M1_s[:,clm] + M2_s[:,clm]
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scipy/sparse/compressed.py:728: SparseEfficiencyWarning: Changing the sparsity structure of a csc_matrix is expensive. lil_matrix is more efficient.
  SparseEfficiencyWarning)
```

Those extra 8 elements are all 0, as can be seen in `Mslicep_s.data`.  Evidently it is inserting the dense version of your sum:

```
In [355]: (M1_s[:,clm] + M2_s[:,clm]).A
Out[355]: 
array([[ 0,  3,  6],
       [12,  0,  0],
       [18,  0, 21],
       [27,  0, 33],
       [ 0,  0,  0]])
```

My guess it is favoring speed over storage.

I clean up the matrix:

```
In [347]: Mslicep_s.eliminate_zeros()    
In [348]: Mslicep_s
Out[348]: 
<5x5 sparse matrix of type '<type 'numpy.int32'>'
    with 12 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Column format>
```

So as an immediate improvement, you could preform this step at each iteration.

With dense arrays, selecting columns with a list like `clm` is 'advanced indexing', and produces a copy, not a faster view.  The `csc` format is the best sparse format for selecting columns like this, but `M1_s[:,clm]` is still a copy.  And as you can see, inserting values into a `csc` matrix is both time and space consuming.  I'm not sure if changing the format of `Mslicep_s` would help or not. `lil` is supposed to be better for modifying sparsity, though changing rows would be better than columns.

It's worth keeping in mind that `csc` and `csr` formats are optimized for matrix multiplication calculations.  They even do things like `.sum()` with a multiplication.  In general you will get better performance, both with time and memory, if you can cast you calculations in those terms.  Indexing is not a strong point for sparse matricies.

If the calculations that you do, do not change the sparsity (don't add nonzeros), then you could make the changes to the `.data` attribute array directly.  But it does require understanding the storage layout.

```
<todo: code to translate [:,clm] to idx array>
Mslice_s.data[idx] = M1_s.data[idx] + M2_s.data[idx]
```

---

This appears to be the correct `idx`:

```
idx = np.concatenate([np.arange(M1_s.indptr[i], M1_s.indptr[i+1]) for i in clm])
# array([0, 1, 2, 5, 6, 7, 8])
```

There may be a more direct way of calculating this, but I think it has the right idea - select ranges based on the selected `.indptr` values.

Comment: Thanks very much for your answer. I should have been more clear that my operations do not change the sparsity of the matrices.

So in that case you suggest writing my own code to do the indexing and then modifying the data array. I'll try that tomorrow.

Comment: I found a tentative way of calculating the data indexes.

Comment: Tried and tested. It works and it works fast. I also understand why your idx are correct, after reading: https://scipy-lectures.github.io/advanced/scipy_sparse/csc_matrix.html

Thanks very much again. Would upvote if I had the rep to do so.